# Optimize python script for speed

Tags: python, optimization

I am working on the following script for python2.7 which "works" on small files.

I ran a sample on an input file of 188kB and it took approx. 1.15 min to complete. However, I need to process a 5GB file using this script and I did the math, it will take 11.48 years to finish it the way it is now.

sample input1

```
aba_transit_number  com
abaca   plt|sub|sub|sub
abacus  art|art
abalone anm
abamp   qud
```

sample input2

```
zoonosis-n  of+n-j+n-the-development-n  
zoonosis-n  of+n-j+n-the-j-collection-n 1
zoonosis-n  of+n-j+n-the-j-success-n    1
```

Can someone provide me insight on how to optimize my script for computation speed??

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    from __future__ import division
    from collections import defaultdict, Counter
    import codecs
    import random

    mapping = dict()

#### takes as input a file with the following input1:


    with codecs.open ("input1", "rb", "utf-8") as oSenseFile:
        for line in oSenseFile:
            concept, conceptClass = line.split()
            mapping[concept + '-n'] = conceptClass

    lemmas = set()


#### takes as input2 a file with the following format


    with codecs.open('input2', "rb", "utf-8") as oIndexFile:
        for line in oIndexFile: 
            lemma = line.split()[0]
            if lemma in mapping.keys():
                lemmas.add(lemma)

### randomly splits input2 into 2 files -- 80% and 20% 
# -- and prints the 20% directly  into out 2 for the other 80% 
# --- it matches each 1st column in input2 with the first column in input 1 
# -- if it is a match - it replaces it with the corresponding value in Col2 of  Input1     
# --- if there is more than one volume in Col2 of Input 1 
# -- it prints all of the possible combinations and divides the freq (Col4 in Input2) 
# by the number of values present 

        training_lemmas = random.sample(lemmas, int(len(lemmas) * 0.8))

    classFreqs = defaultdict(lambda: Counter())

    with codecs.open('out1', 'wb', 'utf-8') as testOutfile:
        with codecs.open('input2', "rb", "utf-8") as oIndexFile:            
            for line in oIndexFile:
                lemmaTAR, slot, filler, freq = line.split()
                if lemmaTAR in training_lemmas:
                    senses = mapping[lemmaTAR].split(u'|')
                    for sense in senses:
                        classFreqs[sense][tuple([slot, filler])] += int(freq) / len(senses)
                elif lemmaTAR in lemmas:
                    testOutfile.write(line)

    with codecs.open('out2', 'wb', 'utf-8') as oOutFile:
        for sense in sorted(classFreqs.keys()):
            for slotfill in classFreqs[sense].keys():
                 string_slotfill = '\t'.join(list(slotfill))
                 outstring = '\t'.join([sense, string_slotfill, str(classFreqs[sense][slotfill])])
                 oOutFile.write(outstring + '\n')
```

Comment: Don't write `.keys()`!

Comment: see updated question --- okay, simply removing .keys() will improve speed?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. [See §3 of this answer for an explanation.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/33549/11728)

Comment: Make `training_lemmas` a `set`.

Comment: You mention a 5 GB file but you have two inputs. Which is large, or both?

Comment: ONly input 2 is large -- it is the file in which the replacing will occur - the other file (input1) is 1.8 mb

Comment: I removed .keys() - no improvement in time - in fact, it seems to go slower :s

Comment: Let's start at the beginning: Include in the question what that does.

Comment: Did you remove *all* the `.keys()`? The one in `if lemma in mapping.keys():` is likely to be the main issue. Which part of the code is slow? You should split it into functions and profile. Can you make your data (the small version) available?

Comment: Update, I removed all `.()keys` and also changed `training_lemmas` to sets. I also removed `codecs.open()`, which seemed to significantly slow down the reading of the large input file. With these changes, it brought down the total processing time (on all the data) to 25 minutes (albeit using almost a full 16GB of memory), but the computation time is much more reasonable than 11 years. Thank you all very much for all of the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all usages of the keys method. Note, this was already mentioned in the comments to your question, but it seems to have mostly done the trick for your problem.