# N-puzzle program solved using A* search

Tags: python, python-2.x, pathfinding, taxicab-geometry

I coded the following program to solve the n-puzzle problem with n = 3. Are there any suggestions regarding readability and variable names?

```
import heapq
from random import shuffle
import math


n=3
fBoard = [1,2,3,
          4,5,6,
          7,8,0]

board = [i for i in range(9)]
shuffle(board)

print(board)
aStar()


class Board():

    def __init__(self,boardList,cost,parent):
        self._array = boardList
        self.heuristic = calcHeuristic(self._array)
        self.cost = cost
        self.totalCost = self.cost + self.heuristic
        self.parent = parent
        self.hashvalue = hash(tuple(self._array))

    def _printBoard(self):
        for var in range(len(self._array)):
            if var%3==0 and var!=0:
                print "\n",self._array[var],",",
            else:
                print self._array[var],",",

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.hashvalue

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self._array == other._array

def aStar():
    pq = []
    cost = {}
    visited = {}
    start = Board(board,0,None)
    end = Board(fBoard,99,None)
    heapq.heappush(pq,(start.totalCost,start))
    while pq:
        tmp_tuple = heapq.heappop(pq)
        tmp_board = tmp_tuple[1]
        if tmp_board.heuristic == 0:
            end = tmp_board
            break

        index = tmp_board._array.index(0)
        x = index/3
        y = index%3
        listOfMoves = checkMove(x,y)

        for move in listOfMoves:
            moveBoard = tmp_board._array[:]
            moveIndex = move[0]*3 + move[1]
            moveBoard[index],moveBoard[moveIndex] = moveBoard[moveIndex],moveBoard[index]
            newBoard = Board(moveBoard,tmp_board.cost+1,tmp_board)
            new_cost = newBoard.totalCost
            if newBoard not in visited or new_cost < cost[newBoard]:
                cost[newBoard] = new_cost
                visited[newBoard] = 1
                newBoard.parent = tmp_board
                heapq.heappush(pq,(newBoard.totalCost,newBoard))

    var = end
    while var != start:
        print "\n"
        var._printBoard()
        var = var.parent

    print "\n"
    var._printBoard()

def manhattanDist(index,element):
    idx = fBoard.index(element)
    manhattan = 0
    fBoard_x = idx/3
    fBoard_y = idx%3
    x = index/3
    y = index%3
    manhattan += math.fabs(x-fBoard_x)
    manhattan += math.fabs(y-fBoard_y)
    return manhattan


def calcHeuristic(array):
    boardList = array
    heuristic = 0
    for var in boardList:
        x = var/3
        y = var%3
        if fBoard.index(var) != boardList.index(var):
            heuristic+=1
        heuristic+=manhattanDist(boardList.index(var),var)
    return heuristic


def checkMove(x,y):
    listOfMoves = [[x,y]]
    if(x+1<n):
        listOfMoves.append([x+1,y])
    if(x-1>=0):
        listOfMoves.append([x-1,y])
    if(y-1>=0):
        listOfMoves.append([x,y-1])
    if(y+1<n):
        listOfMoves.append([x,y+1])

    return listOfMoves
```

Comment: See [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/33473/11728) and its answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any suggestions regarding readability and variable names?

You should follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official Python coding style guide.
For example:

- Put spaces around operators. Instead of `var%3==0`, write as `var % 3 == 0`
- Put spaces after commas separating parameters. Instead of `Board(fBoard,99,None)`, write as `Board(fBoard, 99, None)`
- Use `snake_case` for naming variables and methods instead of `camelCase`
- Use `PascalCase` for naming classes

What is an `fBoard`? It's not easy to guess, so that's not a good name.

#### Don't execute code in global scope

These lines are executed immediately when the script is imported,
which is not good:

> ```
> n=3
> fBoard = [1,2,3,
>           4,5,6,
>           7,8,0]
>
> board = [i for i in range(9)]
> shuffle(board)
>
> print(board)
> aStar()
> ```

It would be better to move them into a `main` function,
and call that function from a `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard, like this:

```
def main():
    n=3
    fBoard = [1,2,3,
              4,5,6,
              7,8,0]

    board = [i for i in range(9)]
    shuffle(board)

    print(board)
    aStar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will make your script more reusable, and it will help you avoid some obscure bugs that can happen by variable shadowing.

#### Get ready for Python 3

It's not too difficult to make this script work with Python 3 too.
All it takes is adapting your `print` statements a little bit.
In some cases it's as trivial as adding `(...)`, for example:

> ```
> print "\n"
> ```

Rewrite as:

```
print("\n")
```

When you don't want the automatic newline, for example here:

> ```
> print "\n",self._array[var],",",
> ```

You can add the `end=''` parameter:

```
print("\n",self._array[var],",", end='')
```

Comment: The last example needs `from __future__ import print_function` at the top in Python 2.

Comment: For Python 3 compatibility, integer division must use `//`.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions regarding design? use of classes and data structures?