# Slow 8/15-puzzle IDA*

Tags: python, performance, sliding-tile-puzzle, a-star

I am trying to find the optimal solution for a given [15-puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle). So far as I can tell, the algorithm works (on simple instances of 8-puzzle), but is extremely slow for complex starting states (order of 100 seconds), and practically unsolvable with 15 tiles.
I know finding the optimal solution is hard but I think I may be using the language in an efficient way here.

`IDAStarSolver.solve()` contains the starting point for computing the solution, although most of the operations are done in the `Board` class.

This is the class containing the solver:

```
import sys
from heapq import heappop, heappush
from src.State import State

class IDAStarSolver:
    def __init__(self, board, heuristic='manhattan'):
        self.solution = []
        self.initial = board
        self.heuristic = heuristic

    def solve(self):
        bound = getattr(self.initial, self.heuristic)

        while True:
            t = self.search(self.initial, 0, bound)
            if t == 'FOUND':
                return bound
            if t == sys.maxsize:
                return 'NOT_FOUND'
            bound = t

    def search(self, node, g, bound):
        f = g + getattr(node, self.heuristic)
        if f > bound:
            return f
        if getattr(node, self.heuristic) == 0:
            return 'FOUND'
        minimum = sys.maxsize
        for neighbour in node.neighbours():
            t = self.search(neighbour, g + 1, bound)
            if t == 'FOUND':
                self.solution.append(node)
                return 'FOUND'
            if t < minimum:
                minimum = t
        return minimum

    def moves(self):
        return len(self.solution)
```

And the Board is represented as follows:

```
from copy import copy
import numpy as np

class Board:
    """ A nxn board for with n^2 - 1 tiles """

    def __init__(self, tiles=None, size=3):
        if tiles is None:
            self.dim = size
            self.tiles = self.generate_board(size)
            while not self.is_solvable():
                self.tiles = self.generate_board(size)
        else:
            self.dim = len(tiles)
            self.tiles = tiles

        self.zero_row = np.where(self.tiles == 0)[0][0]
        self.zero_column = np.where(self.tiles == 0)[1][0]
        self.manhattan = self._manhattan()

    def __copy__(self):
        cls = self.__class__
        new_copy = cls.__new__(cls)
        new_copy.tiles = np.copy(self.tiles)
        new_copy.manhattan = self.manhattan
        new_copy.dim = self.dim
        new_copy.zero_row = self.zero_row
        new_copy.zero_column = self.zero_column
        return new_copy

    def _manhattan(self):
        manhattan = 0
        for i in range(self.dim):
            for j in range(self.dim):
                if self.tiles[i][j] != 0:
                    row = (self.tiles[i][j] - 1) // self.dim
                    column = (self.tiles[i][j] - 1) % self.dim
                    manhattan += abs(i - row) + abs(j - column)
        return manhattan

    def equals(self, board):
        """
        :param Board board: Test board
        """
        return np.array_equal(board.tiles, self.tiles)

    def swap_zero(self, i0, j0):
        """
        Swaps tile at i0, j0 with the zero tile
        """
        # Recalculate manhattan distance
        row = (self.tiles[i0][j0] - 1) // self.dim
        column = (self.tiles[i0][j0] - 1) % self.dim
        self.manhattan -= abs(i0 - row) + abs(j0 - column)
        self.manhattan += abs(self.zero_row - row) + abs(self.zero_column - column)

        # Swap tiles
        self.tiles[i0][j0], self.tiles[self.zero_row, self.zero_column] = \
                self.tiles[self.zero_row, self.zero_column], self.tiles[i0, j0]
        # Update zero row and column
        self.zero_row = i0
        self.zero_column = j0

    def neighbours(self):
        neighbours = []

        # The zero tile can be swapped with tile above
        if self.zero_row > 0:
            neighbour = copy(self)
            neighbour.swap_zero(self.zero_row - 1, self.zero_column)
            neighbours.append(neighbour)

        # The zero tile can be swapped with tile below
        if self.zero_row < self.dim - 1:
            neighbour = copy(self)
            neighbour.swap_zero(self.zero_row + 1, self.zero_column)
            neighbours.append(neighbour)

        # The zero tile can be swapped with the tile to its left
        if self.zero_column > 0:
            neighbour = copy(self)
            neighbour.swap_zero(self.zero_row, self.zero_column - 1)
            neighbours.append(neighbour)

        # The zero tile can be swapped with the tile to its right
        if self.zero_column < self.dim - 1:
            neighbour = copy(self)
            neighbour.swap_zero(self.zero_row, self.zero_column + 1)
            neighbours.append(neighbour)
        return neighbours

    def is_solved(self):
        """
        Checks if the board is the goal position
        """
        return self.manhattan() == 0

    def is_solvable(self):
        """
        Checks if the board is solvable
        """
        tiles = np.ndarray.flatten(self.tiles)
        dim = self.dim * self.dim

        inversions = 0
        for i in range(dim):
            for j in range(i, dim):
                if tiles[i] != 0 and tiles[j] != 0 and tiles[i] > tiles[j]:
                    inversions += 1

        return inversions % 2 == 0

    @staticmethod
    def generate_board(size):
        arr = np.arange(size ** 2)
        np.random.shuffle(arr)
        arr = arr.reshape(size, size)
        return arr


    def __str__(self):
        return np.array_str(self.tiles)
```

And the State:

```
import functools

@functools.total_ordering
class State:
    def __init__(self, current, previous, moves):
        """
        :param current: The current board position
        :param previous: The previous board position
        :param moves: The number of moves made to get to the current board position
        """
        self.current = current
        self.moves = moves
        self.previous = previous
        self.score = self._score()

    def _score(self):
        return self.current.manhattan + self.moves

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.score < other.score

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.score == other.score
```

Comment: The A* algorithm finds the *best* solution — and in order to do so it has to examine a lot of alternatives in order to prove that the solution it finds really is the best. [See here for details.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/86608/11728) If you are prepared to accept *any* solution (even if you can't prove it is the best) then other algorithms can be much faster on this problem.

Comment: The goal was to find the optimal solution, but I'm still curious about alternate approaches for non-optimal solutions so thanks for the link. The main problem here is that there is still issues with puzzles >35 moves, and according to what I've seen, these should be practically solvable

Answer (score 1):

You can use a better heuristic than Manhattan distance. Take a look at the [pattern database heuristic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6616/need-a-practical-solution-for-creating-pattern-database5-5-5-for-15-puzzle). The speedup here would be massive.